# How to create an automation for tplink pharos cpe520 using xpath with selenium and python for log in?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to create an automation for my tplink pharos cpe520
This is the full xpath
`"/html/body/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/input"` it never change. I have to use xpath because every time the id is changed.
this is the xpath

```
//*[@id="widget--95952b3d-c134-3cfe-dd46-1a85b70c6882"]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/input
```

this is a new xpath

```
//*[@id="widget--059a411f-7134-3cfe-ec40-3c71bd80af37"]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/input
```

as you can see it changed
[image: this is the image with the child nodes][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNvbI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']']"))).send_keys("Test")
```

Note : add below impports to your solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: this is the error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='text']"}

Comment: Can you please share your url ? Or else please check your element is not within iframe

Comment: it's not inside of iframe, I'cant share my url because Im from Cuba, I think it doesnt work

Comment: //div[@class="widget-wrap-outer text-wrap-outer"]//div[@class="widget-wrap text-wrap"]//span[2]//input     try this XPATH

Comment: Another option for the locator : `//div[starts-with(@id,"widget")][contains(@id,"-3cfe-")]/div[starts-with(@class,"widget-wrap-outer")]//input[@type="text"]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with "implicitly_wait(5)" before I get the link. It was not a problem from xpath.